SQLAlchemy and Progress Openedge 10.2b
I'm trying to improve performance of an app I'm making that calls onto an old SQL Server using progress openedge 10.2b drivers. However, I can't figure out how to make a working connection string with SQLalchemy (or if it's even compatible with older drivers.
con = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Progress OpenEdge 10.2B Driver};HOST=ip address here;PORT=1234;DATABASE=mydb;UID=myuid;PWD=mypw')

Works, but no SQLAlchemy string I try works. for example
# Connection string parameters
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(
    'DRIVER={Progress OpenEdge 10.2B Driver};'
    'HOST=ip address here;'
    'PORT=1234;'
    'DATABASE=mydb;'
    'UID=myuid;'
    'PWD=mypw'
)

# Create the engine using the correct format
engine = create_engine(f'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={params}')

doesn't work at all, nor does typing out the string.

Using SQLAlchemy's mssql+pyodbc:// dialect will only work in this case if the "Progress OpenEdge" database is 100% compatible with Microsoft SQL Server.
